# Java - OOP - enforce specific implementation during compile time

Tags: java, oop

My code has a set of "factories" (`IfaceProducerProcessor`) producing different inner implementations of the same interface (`Iface`). Those factories should also be able to later perform some processing on an instance they produced, but not on other implementations of `Iface`.

Needless to say, the calling code should not be aware of the implementation details or inner interfaces of specific `Iface` instance, only that it should pass it to its original producer alone for processing.

How can I enforce that only the same concrete class be passed to the class that produced it? Generics maybe?

```
interface Iface {
    void foo();
}

interface IfaceProducerProcessor {
    Iface produceIface();
    void processIface(Iface iface);
}

class A implements IfaceProducerProcessor {
    Iface produceIface() {
        return new AIfaceImpl();
    }

    void processIface(Iface iface) {
        // How to enforce AIfaceImpl in compile-time?
        if (!(iface instanceof AIfaceImpl)) {
            throw IlleagalArgumentException("Expected instanceof AIfaceImpl.");
        }

        ...

        ((AIfaceImpl)iface).bar();

        ...
    }

    class AIfaceImpl implements Iface {
        // implementation of foo() ...

        void bar() {

        }
    }
}

class B implements IfaceProducerProcessor {

    ...

    class BIfaceImpl implements Iface {

        ...

    }
}

...
```

If it is obvious that I have a design flaw I will be happy to hear what it is and how to correct it, but bear in mind this is a simplified example of my code, and the specific details I can't get into led me to the given design...

Answer (score 2):

Your guess with the generics may work the best, consider following change to the `IfaceProducerProcessor`. Note the generic parameter `I` which is boundet to be an implementation of `Iface` only:

```
interface IfaceProducerProcessor<I extends Iface> {
    I produceIface();
    void processIface(I iface);
}
```

Which then the class `A` implements with the following definition:

```
class A implements IfaceProducerProcessor<AIfaceImpl>{
     public AIfaceImpl produceIface(){
         /* ... */
     }

     public void processIface(AIfaceImpl iface){
         /* ... */
     }
}
```

That way you're enforcing via the compiler that you only want to use `AIfaceImpl` in this specific `IfaceProducerProcessor`.

The same can then be done for every implementation of `IfaceProducerProcessor`:

```
class B implements IfaceProducerProcessor<BIfaceImpl>{
    /* ... */
}
```

And so on.

Comment: this is good, but it leaks the `Iface` implementing class. Can it be done with generics the other way around, meaning something like `Iface<P extends IfaceProducerProcessor>`?

Comment: @Elist this is not possible, at least not at compile time